# How to replace mdns4_minimal with BIND?

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, dns, bind

Have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version.
According to task should install BIND as DNS server.
I noticed in nsswitch.conf has:

`hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

Could you please explain what does `mdns4_minimal` and `mdns4` mean and how to make the system use local BIND instance to resolve DNS queries?

Yes, I know how to start/stop BIND.

```
systemctl enable bind9
systemctl start/stop bind9.
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## mDNS or Multicast DNS service

It is provided by **Avahi/Bonjour** daemon, which lets small network computers to use names even if no central DNS is present. It uses by default the `.local` domain.

- If you are not using `.local` for your DNS server then set DNS after mDNS in  `nsswitch.conf` (default)

  ```
  hosts: files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
  ```

  Otherwise `.local` is used by your DNS server (no use for mdns service)

  ```
  hosts: files dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4_minimal mdns4
  ```

### What is the difference between mdns4_minimal and mdns4?

To answer you, it is better to let know how to I collect such info and learn by yourself :) (`##` is for comment to tell objective for the command below it)

```
## Update "locate" database
~$ sudo updatedb
## Search for file with "mdns4_minimal" in its name
~$ locate mdns4_minimal
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2

## Look for which package installs that file
~$ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
libnss-mdns:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2

## List all files from same package
~$ dpkg -L libnss-mdns:amd64
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libnss-mdns
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns
/usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns/README.html
/usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns/style.css
/usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns/changelog.Debian.gz
/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns6.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2

## "README.html" looks the only documentation there, we open it
~$ xdg-open /usr/share/doc/libnss-mdns/README.html
```

> **Documentation**
>
> After compiling and installing `nss-mdns` you'll find six new NSS
>   modules in `/lib`:
>
> - `libnss_mdns.so.2`
> - `libnss_mdns4.so.2`
> - `libnss_mdns6.so.2`
> - `libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2`
> - `libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2`
> - `libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2`
>
> `libnss_mdns.so.2` resolves both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses,
>   `libnss_mdns4.so.2` only IPv4 addresses and `libnss_mdns6.so.2` only
>   IPv6 addresses. Due to the fact that most mDNS responders only
>   register local IPv4 addresses via mDNS, most people will want to use
>   `libnss_mdns4.so.2` exclusively. Using `libnss_mdns.so.2` or
>   `libnss_mdns6.so.2` in such a situation causes long timeouts when
>   resolving hosts since most modern Unix/Linux applications check for
>   IPv6 addresses first, followed by a lookup for IPv4.
>
> `libnss_mdns{4,6,}_minimal.so` (new in version 0.8) is mostly
>   identical to the versions without `_minimal`. However, they differ in
>   one way. The minimal versions will always deny to resolve host names
>   that don't end in `.local` or addresses that aren't in the range
>   `169.254.x.x` (the range used by
>   [IPV4LL/APIPA/RFC3927](http://files.zeroconf.org/rfc3927.txt).)
>   Combining the `_minimal` and the normal NSS modules allows us to make
>   mDNS authoritative for Zeroconf host names and addresses (and thus
>   creating no extra burden on DNS servers with always failing requests)
>   and use it as fallback for everything else.

### IPv6 Support

- `files` & `dns` NSS modules, both supports resolving IPv6 besides IPv4.
- However, `mdns4` & `mdns4_minimal` are only for IPv4.

  Same for `mdns6` & `mdns6_minimal` are only for IPv6.

  `mdns` & `mdns_minimal` support both IPv4 & IPv6, but its use should be avoided if only a single IP version is deployed in the network. Because It will try to resolve to IPv6 then fall-back to IPv4, which can create additional delay.

  BTW, the current default setup of Avahi is IPv4, it is a decentralized service. So to go with IPv6, alls machine should reconfigured to use IPv6 in `nsswitch` and `avahi` too.

### Are there any other `[]`'s similar to `[NOTFOUND=return]`?

Yes, as we can see from [`man nsswitch.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)

> ```
>    An action may also be specified following a service specification.   The  action  modifies
>    the  behavior  following  a  result obtained from the preceding data source.  Action items
>    take the general form:
>
>        [STATUS=ACTION]
>        [!STATUS=ACTION]
>
>    where
>
>        STATUS => success | notfound | unavail | tryagain
>        ACTION => return | continue
>
>    The ! negates the test, matching all possible results except the one specified.  The  case
>    of the keywords is not significant.
>
>    The  STATUS  value is matched against the result of the lookup function called by the pre‐
>    ceding service specification, and can be one of:
>
>        success     No error occurred and the requested entry is returned.  The default action
>                    for this condition is "return".
>
>        notfound    The  lookup succeeded, but the requested entry was not found.  The default
>                    action for this condition is "continue".
>
>        unavail     The service is permanently unavailable.  This can  mean  either  that  the
>                    required file cannot be read, or, for network services, that the server is
>                    not available or does not allow queries.  The default action for this con‐
>                    dition is "continue".
>
>        tryagain    The  service is temporarily unavailable.  This could mean a file is locked
>                    or a server currently cannot accept more connections.  The default  action
>                    for this condition is "continue".
>
>    The ACTION value can be one of:
>
>        return      Return  a result now.  Do not call any further lookup functions.  However,
>                    for compatibility reasons, if this is the selected action  for  the  group
>                    database and the notfound status, and the configuration file does not con‐
>                    tain the initgroups line, the next lookup function is always called, with‐
>                    out affecting the search result.
>
>        continue    Call the next lookup function.
> ```

### Related Questions:

- [Why does the host command not resolve entries in /etc/hosts?](https://serverfault.com/q/498500/79479)

Comment: What is the difference between mdn4_minimal and mdns4? They look the same.

Comment: " and use it as fallback for everything else" it means that usual DNS query would be issued(as a fallback) if mdns4_fails? Last sentence is long and not very clear, could you, please, clarify?

Comment: Yes, for example `files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4` . nsswitch will try `/etc/host`, then `mdns4_minimal` (that try to resolve only `.local`), then regular `dns`  from `/etc/resolv.conf` then return NOT FOUND message. `mdns4` (try to resolve any) is not used.

Comment: And what is the rationale of adding mdns4 after [NOTFOUND=return] if processing will not reach it(mdns4)?

Comment: @BulatM. It is disabled. They left it there to let user know about the available options.

Comment: Are there any other []'s similar to [NOTFOUND=return]?

Comment: Thanks, answered my question. Keep up, you do well, good luck.

Comment: One more question. Could you please give string for Ipv6 capable hosts, that use also ipv6 queries?

Comment: @BulatM., I have updated my answer, but i'm not quiet sure that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Great info but wasn't clear if "mdns4" would be a direct replacement for "mdns4_minimal dns" (presuming only IP4 in use) or does it do something else?

Comment: @user3161924 No, it is not same thing. `mdns4` is Avahi specific and it will resolve only domains exiting in your zeroconf network and will fails for others. `mdns4_minimal` is for Avahi to resolve only `.local` and `169.254.x.x` that only exist in zeroconf network, and `dns` is for libnss_dns which it is a different NSS module use system defined DNS to resolve from DNS server (either local system cache or same network or external)