# raspberry.local domain does'nt alawys work

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns, openvpn

I have an raspberry pi 4B as octoprint webserver and I use a Ubuntu 20.04 machine to access it over **octopi.local**.

Recently octopi.local stopped working. I tried `ping octopi.local`, and sometimes it responded with the IP *"192.0.x.x"* (so my home network), other times it responded with *"10.8.x.x"* (from what google said, this is OpenVPN, but I never installed that) and sometimes it is *"100.x.x.x"* (which is from a service called tailscale).
I disabled the openvpn serivce on the raspberry pi, because there was no response on 10.8.0.1, now it switches between the tailscale and the local-network ip randomly.

I already tried editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to `hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4`, that resolved the 10.8.x.x error...

I am kinda new to such networking stuff, so I hope you understand what I mean.
I am trying to point octopi.local always to 192.168.0.x

Comment: Put `mdns4_minimal` before `dns` in `nsswitch.conf` see https://askubuntu.com/a/853284/26246 for more info. what missing too that avahi on target machine should broadcast the local address not those from VPN's. Let me see if can find something about it.

Comment: Try setting `allow-interfaces=` or `deny-interfaces=` in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf ` of target machine so it uses on correct interface.